# Textures Bleeding / Corruption in OpenGL Batch Renderer

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, rendering, glfw

Working on an engine in C++ and implemented a batch renderer based on the [Cherno's video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrATfBNZ98f5vZ8nJ6UengEkZUMC4fy5). Which appeared to work fine for a while. Recently noticed that on 1 of the 2 computers working on the project, there was weird bleeding of one texture into another for the sprites.

[image: Sprite textures bleeding into one another]

[image: Sprite 1 Bleeds into Sprite 2]([https://imgur.com/pSolKRb]

After a little research we noticed that specifically, the bleeding happened based on the order they were rendered. Where the first rendered sprite had no problems, and following sprites were mostly correct with a small section of pixels being from the texture of the last drawn sprite.

We believe the issue is something to do with the shaders, but it is also possible that there is something wrong with the batch renderer.

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;
layout (location = 3) in int aTexIndex;

out vec4 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;
flat out int TexIndex;

uniform mat4 uViewProjection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = uViewProjection * vec4(aPos, 1.0);

    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
    TexIndex = aTexIndex;
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec4 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;
flat in int TexIndex;

uniform sampler2D ourTextures[32];

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(ourTextures[TexIndex], TexCoord) * ourColor;
}
```

**Batch Renderer.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "Shader.h"
#include "Memory/SmartPointers.h"
namespace Engine::Graphics
{
    // TODO: move this struct to a different header.
    struct Vertex
    {
        glm::vec3 pos;
        glm::vec4 col;
        glm::vec2 texCoords;
        i32 texIndex;
    };

    struct BatchData
    {
        GLuint VAO = 0;
        GLuint VB = 0;
        GLuint IB = 0;

        uint32_t indexCount = 0;

        Vertex* vertexBuffer = nullptr;
        Vertex* vertexBufferCurrentOffset = nullptr;

        GLint* textureSlotsArray = nullptr;
        i32 textureSlotIndex = 0;

        glm::mat4x4 currentViewMatrix = glm::mat4x4();
    };

    class BatchRenderer
    {
    public:
        void Init(SharedRef<Shader>& startShader);
        void Destroy();
        GLuint GetVAOID();

        static uint32_t GetMaxBatchSize();
        static uint32_t GetNoTexID();
        static uint32_t GetQuadsDrawnThisFrame();
        static uint32_t GetDrawCallsThisFrame();
        static void ResetQuadCounter();
        static void ResetDrawCallCounter();
        void BeginBatch();
        void EndBatch();
        void Flush();
        void SetShader(SharedRef<Shader>& shaderPassed);

        void DrawQuad(const glm::vec2& position1, const glm::vec2& position2, const glm::vec2& position3, const glm::vec2& position4, const glm::vec4& colour);
        void DrawQuad(const glm::vec2& position1, const glm::vec2& position2, const glm::vec2& position3, const glm::vec2& position4, uint32_t textureID);
        void DrawQuad(const glm::vec2& position1, const glm::vec2& position2, const glm::vec2& position3, const glm::vec2& position4, uint32_t textureID, const glm::vec4& colour);

        void UpdateViewMatrix(const glm::mat4x4& newMatrix);

        SharedRef<Shader> shaderRef;
        BatchData m_batchData;
        friend class BatchManager;

    };
}
```

**Batch Renderer.cpp** - Important Functions, Feel Free to ask for Anything you think I missed.

```
void BatchRenderer::Init(SharedRef<Shader>& startShader)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        assert(m_batchData.vertexBuffer == nullptr && "Batch Renderer already initialized.");
#endif
        shaderRef = startShader;
        shaderRef->Bind();
        GLint maxTextures;
        glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &maxTextures);

        MAX_TEXTURES_PER_BATCH = maxTextures;
        if (MAX_TEXTURES_PER_BATCH > 32)
        {
            MAX_TEXTURES_PER_BATCH = 32;
        }

        m_batchData.vertexBuffer = new Vertex[MAX_VERT_COUNT_PER_BATCH];

        glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_batchData.VAO);
        glBindVertexArray(m_batchData.VAO);

        shaderRef->Bind();

        glGenBuffers(1, &m_batchData.VB);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_batchData.VB);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, MAX_VERT_COUNT_PER_BATCH * sizeof(Vertex), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)(0 * sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)(7 * sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

        //glVertexAttribPointer(3, 1, GL_UNSIGNED, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)(9 * sizeof(float))); 
        glVertexAttribIPointer(3, 1, GL_INT, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)(9 * sizeof(float))); 
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);

        uint32_t* indices = new uint32_t[MAX_INDEX_COUNT_PER_BATCH];
        uint32_t offset = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_INDEX_COUNT_PER_BATCH; i += 6)   
        {
            indices[i] = 0 + offset;
            indices[i + 1] = 1 + offset; 
            indices[i + 2] = 2 + offset;

            indices[i + 3] = 2 + offset;
            indices[i + 4] = 3 + offset;
            indices[i + 5] = 0 + offset;

            offset += 4;
        }

        glGenBuffers(1, &m_batchData.IB);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_batchData.IB);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, MAX_INDEX_COUNT_PER_BATCH * sizeof(uint32_t), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 
        delete[] indices;
        m_batchData.textureSlotsArray = new GLsizei[MAX_TEXTURES_PER_BATCH];
        m_batchData.textureSlotsArray[0] = noTexID; 
        GLint* samplers = new int32_t[MAX_TEXTURES_PER_BATCH];
        samplers[0] = 0;
        for (GLint i = 1; i < MAX_TEXTURES_PER_BATCH; i++)
        {
            m_batchData.textureSlotsArray[i] = 0; //zero out data
            samplers[i] = i;
        }
        glUniform1iv(shaderRef->GetUniformIndex("ourTextures"), static_cast<int>(MAX_TEXTURES_PER_BATCH), samplers);

    }

void BatchRenderer::Destroy()
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        assert(m_batchData.vertexBuffer != nullptr && "Batch Renderer not initialized, cannot destroy.");
#endif
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &m_batchData.VAO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_batchData.VB);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_batchData.IB);

        delete[] m_batchData.vertexBuffer;
        delete[] m_batchData.textureSlotsArray;
    }

void BatchRenderer::BeginBatch()
    {
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset = m_batchData.vertexBuffer;
    }

    void BatchRenderer::EndBatch()
    {
        glBindVertexArray(m_batchData.VAO);
        shaderRef->Bind();
        GLsizeiptr totalSize = (uint8_t*)m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset - (uint8_t*)m_batchData.vertexBuffer;
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_batchData.VB);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, totalSize, m_batchData.vertexBuffer);
    }

    void BatchRenderer::Flush() 
    {
        glBindVertexArray(m_batchData.VAO);
        shaderRef->Bind();
        shaderRef->SetMat4x4("uViewProjection", m_batchData.currentViewMatrix);
        for (i32 i = 0; i < m_batchData.textureSlotIndex; i++)
        {
            glBindTextureUnit(i, m_batchData.textureSlotsArray[i]);
        }
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_batchData.indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

        m_batchData.indexCount = 0;
        m_batchData.textureSlotIndex = 1;

#ifdef EDITOR
        drawCallsThisFrame++;
#endif
    }

void BatchRenderer::DrawQuad(const glm::vec2& position1, const glm::vec2& position2, const glm::vec2& position3, const glm::vec2& position4, uint32_t textureID, const glm::vec4& colour)
    {
        if (m_batchData.indexCount > QUICK_LOWER_INDEX_ACCESS || m_batchData.textureSlotIndex >= MAX_TEXTURES_PER_BATCH)
        {
            EndBatch();
            Flush();
            BeginBatch();
        }

        i32 textureIndex = -1;
        for (i32 i = 0; i < m_batchData.textureSlotIndex; i++)
        {
            if (m_batchData.textureSlotsArray[i] == textureID)
            {
                textureIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (textureIndex == -1)
        {
            textureIndex = m_batchData.textureSlotIndex;
            m_batchData.textureSlotsArray[m_batchData.textureSlotIndex] = static_cast<i32>(textureID);
            m_batchData.textureSlotIndex++;
        }

        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->pos = { position1.x, position1.y, 0.0f };
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->col = colour;
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->texCoords = { 0.0f, 0.0f };
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->texIndex = textureIndex;
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset++;

        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->pos = { position2.x, position2.y, 0.0f };
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->col = colour;
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->texCoords = { 1.0f, 0.0f };
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->texIndex = textureIndex;
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset++;

        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->pos = { position3.x, position3.y, 0.0f };
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->col = colour;
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->texCoords = { 1.0f, 1.0f };
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->texIndex = textureIndex;
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset++;

        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->pos = { position4.x, position4.y, 0.0f };
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->col = colour;
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->texCoords = { 0.0f, 1.0f };
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset->texIndex = textureIndex;
        m_batchData.vertexBufferCurrentOffset++;

        m_batchData.indexCount += 6;
#ifdef EDITOR
        quadCountThisFrame++;
#endif
    }
```

As mentioned above, the error is only on 1 of 2 PCs working on the project (**AMD RX 580** has the bug), if that information is useful.

Comment: `ourTextures[TexIndex]` is undefined behavior, because `TexIndex` is not dynamically uniform.

Comment: @Rabbid76 how would we solve that, is there a better way to pass in the texture index on a per vertex basis that is defined behaviour?

Comment: @MatthewLoveday: alternatives are: [array textures](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Array_Texture), texture atlases, or bindless textures.

Comment: `sampler2DArray`. See [Sampler](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ourTextures[TexIndex]` is undefined behavior, because`ourTextures` is an array of samplers and `TexIndex` is a fragment shader input. A ragment shader input is not a [Dynamically uniform expression](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Dynamically_uniform_expression).

See GLSL version 3.30, which you use (from [OpenGL Shading Language 3.30 Specification - 4.1.7 Samplers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.3.30.pdf)):

> Samplers aggregated into arrays
>   within a shader (using square brackets [ ]) can only be indexed with integral constant expressions

See GLSL version 4.60 (most recent) (from [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 4.1.7. Opaque Types](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#opaque-types)):
(This rule applies to all the versions since GLSL 4.00)

> When aggregated into arrays within a shader, these types can only be indexed with a dynamically uniform expression, or texture lookup will result in undefined values.

Thus, neither in the GLSL version which you use, nor in the most recent version, array of samplers can be indexed by an vertex shader input (attribute).

Since GLSL 4.00 it would be possible to index an array of samplers by an uniform, because indexing by a uniform variable is a [dynamically uniform expression](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Dynamically_uniform_expression).

---

I recommend to use s `sampler2DArray` (see [Sampler](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL))) rather than an array of `sampler2D`.
When you use a `sampler2DArray`, then you don't need any indexing at all, because  the "index" is encoded in the 3rd component of the texture coordinate at texture lookup (see [`Texture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texture.xhtml)).